# Wordpress search database values and return

Tags: wordpress, return, call

i'm have been searching for a code that will do some thing like this in WordPress and but it **CANT call on woocommerce**

nothing seems to work

```
if

get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price' is greater then 1)

do this

else

do this code
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the place where you are using this function.

Imagine you are trying to edit a product page. In your woocommerce templates folder, you find for example: price.php

Usually there is one global variable available already, and if it's not available you can set it with `global $product`. With `$product->get_id()` you can get the product id then.

With the global variable the sale price is then available like [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) `$price = $product->get_sale_price();`

In order to make the if statement, you need the data so then the next step. Maybe your price is empty for some reason, which returns undefined, making it difficult to do the if statement

```
if (empty($price))
        $price = 0;
if($price > 1))
        // do your thing
```

Answer (score 0):

$my_post_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'sale_price', true);

```
    if ( ! empty ( $my_post_meta ) ) {

    do code here

    } else 

   do other code
```

this works for me